# ffmpeg output with assumed duration 0 on Android

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, metadata

I noticed that videos generated by FFMPEG have a duration of 0 on **Android** even when I try a full clone.
I tried the following commands, but the only one that had any effect was with `-movflags faststart`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy                                                 output.mp4
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -movflags use_metadata_tags                     output.mp4
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -movflags use_metadata_tags     -map_metadata 0 output.mp4
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -movflags faststart -brand mp42 -map_metadata 0 output.mp4
```

All play normally on **Android**, and the last one appears with the correct time in the gallery. But the problem is uploading to **TikTok**, because despite playing, it thinks that the duration is zero and does not allow uploading.

**INPUT DATA** (recorded by cell phone camera)

```
General
Complete name                  : G:\input.mp4
Format                         : MPEG-4
Format profile                 : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                       : mp42 (isom/mp42)
File size                      : 13.2 MiB
Duration                       : 7 s 647 ms
Overall bit rate               : 14.4 Mb/s
Encoded date                   : UTC 2022-04-17 11:43:02
Tagged date                    : UTC 2022-04-17 11:43:02
com.android.version            : 10

Video
ID                             : 1
Format                         : AVC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                 : High@L3.1
Format settings                : CABAC / 2 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC         : Yes
Format settings, Reference fra : 2 frames
Codec ID                       : avc1
Codec ID/Info                  : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                       : 7 s 647 ms
Source duration                : 7 s 579 ms
Bit rate                       : 14.1 Mb/s
Width                          : 1 280 pixels
Height                         : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 16:9
Rotation                       : 270°
Frame rate mode                : Variable
Frame rate                     : 29.970 (29970/1000) FPS
Minimum frame rate             : 14.940 FPS
Maximum frame rate             : 10 000.000 FPS
Standard                       : NTSC
Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Scan type                      : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.509
Stream size                    : 12.7 MiB (96%)
Source stream size             : 12.7 MiB (96%)
Title                          : VideoHandle
Language                       : English
Encoded date                   : UTC 2022-04-17 11:43:02
Tagged date                    : UTC 2022-04-17 11:43:02
Color range                    : Limited
colour_range_Original          : Full
Color primaries                : BT.709
colour_primaries_Original      : BT.601 PAL
Transfer characteristics       : BT.709
transfer_characteristics_Origi : BT.601
Matrix coefficients            : BT.709
matrix_coefficients_Original   : BT.470 System B/G
mdhd_Duration                  : 7647
Codec configuration box        : avcC

Audio
ID                             : 2
Format                         : AAC LC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                       : mp4a-40-2
Duration                       : 7 s 595 ms
Bit rate mode                  : Constant
Bit rate                       : 96.0 kb/s
Channel(s)                     : 2 channels
Channel layout                 : L R
Sampling rate                  : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                     : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode               : Lossy
Stream size                    : 89.0 KiB (1%)
Title                          : SoundHandle
Language                       : English
Encoded date                   : UTC 2022-04-17 11:43:02
Tagged date                    : UTC 2022-04-17 11:43:02
mdhd_Duration                  : 7595


ffprobe input.mp4
ffprobe version N-104856-g996b13fac4-20211212 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.24.0.498_5075e1f)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20211212
  libavutil      57. 11.100 / 57. 11.100
  libavcodec     59. 14.100 / 59. 14.100
  libavformat    59. 10.100 / 59. 10.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8. 20.100 /  8. 20.100
  libswscale      6.  1.101 /  6.  1.101
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000024a94212600] st: 0 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 3037
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000024a94212600] st: 0 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 3037.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2022-04-17T11:43:02.000000Z
    com.android.version: 10
  Duration: 00:00:07.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14438 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m, progressive), 1280x720, 14043 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.95 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-04-17T11:43:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-04-17T11:43:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

**OUTPUT DATA** (`-c copy -movflags faststart -brand mp42 -map_metadata 0`)

```
General
Complete name                  : G:\output.mp4
Format                         : MPEG-4
Format profile                 : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                       : mp42 (mp42/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                      : 12.8 MiB
Duration                       : 7 s 595 ms
Overall bit rate               : 14.1 Mb/s
Encoded date                   : UTC 2022-04-17 11:43:02
Tagged date                    : UTC 2022-04-17 11:43:02
Writing application            : Lavf59.10.100

Video
ID                             : 1
Format                         : AVC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                 : High@L3.1
Format settings                : CABAC / 2 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC         : Yes
Format settings, Reference fra : 2 frames
Codec ID                       : avc1
Codec ID/Info                  : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                       : 7 s 580 ms
Bit rate                       : 14.0 Mb/s
Width                          : 1 280 pixels
Height                         : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 16:9
Rotation                       : 270°
Frame rate mode                : Variable
Frame rate                     : 29.970 (29970/1000) FPS
Minimum frame rate             : 14.940 FPS
Maximum frame rate             : 10 000.000 FPS
Standard                       : NTSC
Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Scan type                      : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.508
Stream size                    : 12.7 MiB (99%)
Title                          : VideoHandle
Language                       : English
Encoded date                   : UTC 2022-04-17 11:43:02
Tagged date                    : UTC 2022-04-17 11:43:02
Color range                    : Full
Color primaries                : BT.601 PAL
Transfer characteristics       : BT.601
Matrix coefficients            : BT.470 System B/G
Codec configuration box        : avcC

Audio
ID                             : 2
Format                         : AAC LC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                       : mp4a-40-2
Duration                       : 7 s 595 ms
Bit rate mode                  : Constant
Bit rate                       : 96.0 kb/s
Channel(s)                     : 2 channels
Channel layout                 : L R
Sampling rate                  : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                     : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode               : Lossy
Stream size                    : 89.0 KiB (1%)
Title                          : SoundHandle
Language                       : English
Default                        : Yes
Alternate group                : 1
Encoded date                   : UTC 2022-04-17 11:43:02
Tagged date                    : UTC 2022-04-17 11:43:02


ffprobe output.mp4
ffprobe version N-104856-g996b13fac4-20211212 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.24.0.498_5075e1f)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20211212
  libavutil      57. 11.100 / 57. 11.100
  libavcodec     59. 14.100 / 59. 14.100
  libavformat    59. 10.100 / 59. 10.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8. 20.100 /  8. 20.100
  libswscale      6.  1.101 /  6.  1.101
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp42iso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2022-04-17T11:43:02.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf59.10.100
  Duration: 00:00:07.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14119 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m, progressive), 1280x720, 14044 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.95 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-04-17T11:43:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-04-17T11:43:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

, progressive), 1280x720, 14044 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.95 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

I think the problem is the missing *source duration* video meta tag...

Solution or tips?

Comment: You may want to reencode instead of copying the content (remove -c:v copy from your command)

Comment: @mashuptwice The idea is just to change the volume and not change the content, but that doesn't work either, it remains zeroed. To work I need to send to whatsapp and download, with huge quality losses. Whatsapp conversion is recognized.

Comment: Whats the output of `mediainfo` and `ffprobe`?

Comment: @mashuptwice I edited the ask adding the data

Comment: I noticed that moving the video from /Downloads/ to the /DCIM/Camera/ directory it reads correctly in both the gallery and TikTok, regardless of the output format, and this also counts towards the original video transferred to the cloud.

Now I don't know whether to delete my question or leave it for the next one...

Comment: sounds there is some kind of indexing happening with your cloud backup? e.g. there is still a reference to ~/DCIM/Camera/file, while the file resides in ~/Downloads/file? Could you try to delete the file from within your cloud storage/galery, add it to ~/Downloads and see if the same behavior occurs? IMHO it would be better you add some info about the device/OS/version and the cloud provider you are using, as well as your new findings and leave the question for future reference